# next/Image shows only alt during development, but fine in production

Tags: image, next.js

During development, the image become broken and shows alt [image during development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj2gN.png). The source is an url, which is from backend server. After hosting it in vercel, the image is showing fine.

```
 <Image
    rc={image.image}
    alt="Tour Image"
    width={400}
    height={400}
    className="rounded-xl aspect-square object-cover w-[400px] h-[400px]"
  />
```

image.image is the src of image which is correct, image is fine in production